# Using await in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I just upgraded to node 8 and want to start working with async/await. I came across an error which took me a while to solve and I was actually just wondering if there's a more graceful way. I didn't want refactor the whole function at this point in time because of all the secondary refactors it would lead to.

```
async doSomething(stuff) {
...

  return functionThatReturnsPromise()
    .then((a) => ...)
    .then((b) => ...)
    .then((c) => {
      const user = await someService.createUser(stuff, c);
      user.finishSetup();
    });
};
```

is there a way to be able to use `await` in the promise chain without having to refactor everything above to be `async` as well?

Comment: shouldn't that be `.then(async (c) => {` to be at all valid?

Comment: That's probably what I missed when messing with this before... I had wrapped the whole chain in an async IEFE. Thanks!

Comment: in this simple example I wouldn't need await, but in the real code I have, there's stuff that needs to be done to the user.

Comment: yes, `await` can only be used inside a function that is `async` - a function inside an async function isn't async unless it is itself specifically tagged as such :p

Comment: `in this simple example you'd be right` - ok, comment removed :p

Comment: What I don't get is why the function is still using promises when the entire function is an `async` function.

Comment: That's essentially the crux of my issue. The whole function is promise based (heavily) and I don't want to refactor all the functions it uses to be async as well. Ripping out the promise chain is trivial, but any code change can result in errors... Maybe your question is more related to how promises and async/await interact though?

Comment: What "*secondary refactors*" are you talking about?

Comment: `What "secondary refactors" are you talking about?` Making all the other functions in the promise chain async. Though it's a minor thing. The issue is more about not having to restructure the entire function.

Comment: After taking a step back from the original question, you could probably just return the createUser method without doing all the async/await and get the same results?

Comment: You're the second person to suggest that, I'll update the question so other people don't ask the same thing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The callback is not declared as an `async` function. You can only `await` a `Promise` directly inside of an `async` function.

```
async doSomething(stuff) {
// ...

  return functionThatReturnsPromise()
    .then((a) => /* ... */)
    .then((b) => /* ... */)
    .then(async (c) => {
      const user = await someService.createUser(stuff, c);
      return user;
    });
};
```

Moreover, you shouldn't *need* to use `then` if you are leveraging `async` functions.

```
async doSomething(stuff) {
// ...

  const a = await functionThatReturnsPromise();
  const b = // ...
  const c = // ...
  const user = await someService.createUser(stuff, c);
  return user;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I understand now thanks to @Jaromanda X. I also understand that it wouldn't be a concern if I converted to whole function over to async/await, but this is a core function to the application and I'd rather not touch more than I have to, hence the effort to preserve the promise chain and just add the new piece I need.

Comment: What do you mean by _if I converted to whole function over to async/await_? You can `await` any `Promise` from inside an `async` function.

Comment: right now the entire function is a long promise chain. I wanted to avoid converting each "link" in the chain to be `await`ed.

Comment: The calling code shouldn't need to be refactored won't know the difference between invoking an async function or a regular function that returns a promise. By the spec, when an async function is called, it returns a Promise.

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey I see, that's a good decision :) Hopefully there will be some tests in the future to make major refactors like that less uncertain 

Comment: @jensengar just a a little tip , visual studio code converts your whole promise chain code to async/await using right click